# pythonic way for FIFO order in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to populate a dictionary in python but I would like to preserve the order of the keys as they get in - exactly FIFO like a list would do it.

For example,

I read a file called animals.txt containing the following information:

```
animal\tconservation_status\n
dog\tdomesticated\n
tiger\tEN\n
panda\tEN\n
```

I.e.,

```
animals = {'dog':'dom','tiger':'EN', 'panda':'EN'}
>>> for el in animals:
...     print el
... 
tiger
dog
panda
```

And in a FIFO SHOULD have been dog, tiger, panda as they come out...

When I read it into a dictionary the order will not be preserved.  I would like the order to be preserved such that when I do a for loop the FIRST IN is the FIRST OUT.

I.e., 
dog, then tiger, then panda.

Is there a nice way to do this without having to keep an external index or a more complex dictionary structure?  Not sure, sorry for my naivity here...

Comment: In Python 3.7+ You can do dict FIFO pop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662028/80615

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  You use a [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a regular dictionary.

```
>>> d = OrderedDict((x,x) for x in reversed(range(10)) )
>>> d
OrderedDict([(9, 9), (8, 8), (7, 7), (6, 6), (5, 5), (4, 4), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)])
>>> regular = dict((x,x) for x in reversed(range(10)))
>>> regular
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

Notice that the `OrderedDict` preserves the order whereas the regular `dict` does not.

---

```
>>> OrderedDict([('dog','dom'),('tiger','EN'), ('panda','EN')])
OrderedDict([('dog', 'dom'), ('tiger', 'EN'), ('panda', 'EN')])
```

Another gotcha is that you need to pass items to the constructor (or `.update`) in a way that preserves order.  In other words, you can't pass keyword args to the constructor and expect order to be preserved:

```
>>> OrderedDict(dog='dom',tiger='EN',panda='EN')  #doesn't preserve order
OrderedDict([('tiger', 'EN'), ('panda', 'EN'), ('dog', 'dom')])
```