# how to do a dictionary that give the output with a fifo process

Tags: python, dictionary, fifo

i am searching a method or library that use a dict that allow method like:
`element_dict_in({'polo':789})`,and `element_dict_out()` that return me the first relation that was put in the dictionary, the 2 method that i mentioned before are not implemented,it is for clarify my idea:

for example:

```
dict={}
element_dict_in({'polo1':789})
element_dict_in({'polo2':123})
element_dict_in({'polo3':4556})#{'polo1':789,'polo2':123,'polo3':4556}
element_dict_out()#return {'polo1':789}
```

i find this link [pythonic way for FIFO order in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163762/pythonic-way-for-fifo-order-in-dictionary)  but for my it is not enough clear, so
exist something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python actually already has this in the standard library - [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict()
my_dict['polo1'] = 789
my_dict['polo2'] = 123
my_dict['polo3'] = 4556

print(my_dict.popitem(last=False))
# ('polo1', 789)
```

---

Notably, the built-in `dict` type [can do *LIFO* popping but not *FIFO* popping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) if that's acceptable to you, and is generally faster than the `OrderedDict` for most things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do dict FIFO pop with the built-in `dict` type as follows:

```
my_dict.pop(list(my_dict)[0])
```

with `list(my_dict)` you get all the keys

with `list(my_dict)[0]` you get the first one

with `my_dict.pop(list(my_dict)[0])` you get the key of the first one, and pop it

in Python 3.7+

Comment: The suggested approach first constructs a list of *all* the keys from the dictionary, and then takes first item from this list. It is not optimal.
If you checked that the dict is not empty then you can use `my_dict.pop(next(iter(my_dict)))` instead: it uses iterator and avoids constructing unneeded list.